# what are the "coordinates" of an affine variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an affine variety of dimension $d$ inside the affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$. What do we mean when we say "let $u_1,\dots,u_d$ be coordinates of $X$"? Does this mean that we can describe every element of $X$ by a $d$-tuple? If yes, how can we see that?

This terminology appears for example in the solution of problem I.3.15(d) in Hartshorne here: http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~jcutrone/Work/Hartshorne%20Algebraic%20Geometry%20Solutions.pdf

Comment: I don't think he means that. To me it looks like a quick way of referring to the elements one gets out of Noether normalization: $u_1, \dots, u_d \in A(X)$ that are algebraically independent over $k$ such that $A(X)$ is finite over $k[u_1, \dots, u_d]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One says $u_1,\ldots, u_d$ are coordinates on $\mathbf{X}$ if they generate the coordinate ring $k[X_1,\ldots, X_n]/I(\mathbf{X}).$

E.g. If $\mathbf{X}=V(Y-X^2) \subset \mathbb{A}^2$ then the coordinate ring is $k[X,Y]/(Y-X^2)$ which is generated by $x:= X + (Y-X^2)$ so $\{ x \}$ is a set of coordinates for the parabola. The plane $Z=0$ inside $k^3$ has a coordinate ring generated by the images of $X$ and $Y,$ so those are coordinates for that plane.

If values the $\{u_i\}$ are specified, then this determines a value for each $X_i$ because each element $X_i+I(\mathbf{X})$ is generated by the coordinates. The n-tuple $(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ lies on $\mathbf{X}.$ Note that in the special cases where these generators are also algebrically independent (such as when $\mathbf{X}$ is rational), specifying $X_i$ on $\mathbf{X}$ determines the $u_i$ as well.

Back to the parabola example: Specifying $x=a$ gives $X=a, Y=a^2,$ and specifying a point on the parabola determines $x.$

You may also want to look at the top of page 100 of [Vakil's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf) and read around accordingly.

Comment: Question: If we have an affine variety $X$ of dimension $d$, then it is true that there exist precisely $d$ algebraically independent elements among the generators of $A(X)$. But these elements need not generate $A(X)$, right? In the two examples that you give, the algebraically independent elements do generate $A(X)$, but why would that be the case in general?

Comment: @Manos You are correct. I should not have required algebraic independence, simply generation. In the special case where we have both, then specifying $(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ on $\mathbf{X}$ also determines the $u_i$ which is even more in line with out intuition of what coordinates usually do. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok. I wonder what do you think about the solution that i reference. Is it imprecise when they say that $t_1,\dots,t_n,u_1,\dots,u_m$ generate $k[X \times Y]$?

Comment: @Manos Yes they are a bit sloppy. They really mean that the images of $t_1\otimes 1, \ldots, t_n \otimes 1, 1 \otimes u_1, \ldots, 1\otimes u_n$ under the injection defined in part b) are generators for $k[X\times Y].$

Comment: But as we discussed, the $t_i \otimes 1, 1 \otimes u_j$ need not be generators. So in my view, they are just proving that $k[X \times Y]$ has at least $n+m$ algebraically independent elements among its generators.

Comment: I actually found a very rigorous solution here: http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/oldwebpages/Math683Fall2013/Product.pdf.

Comment: I don't think that the link in the OP is assuming that these things generate. It seems like if we put your convention and the OP's convention together then we conclude that all varieties are affine spaces. Unfortunately this is true of the parabola and I can't think of a good example on the spot.